# d3 : can't get values to display when more data is added to a bar chart

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I'm using d3 to build a horizontal bar chart.

When it is first rendered the values are displayed within the bar:

[image: data with values when first loaded]

However, when further data is added something is preventing it and the new bars from showing:

[image: when more data is added with values]

This problem is related to my code to display the values within the bars.

When I remove this chunk of code, the new bars show (just without the values in them):

[image: ad more data without values]

Where am I going wrong?

```
function renderBarChart(data, metric, countryID) {

data = sortByHighestValues(data, metric)

const width = 0.9 * screen.width
const height = 0.8 * screen.height
const margin = { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 30 }
const innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom

const xScale = d3
    .scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d[metric])])
    .range([margin.left, width]);

const yScale = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map((d) => d[countryID]))
    .range([0, innerHeight])
    .padding(0.2);

const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale).ticks(10);


if (!barChartAxisRendered) {

    renderYAxis(width, height, margin, yAxis)
    renderXAxis(width, height, margin, xAxis, innerHeight)

} else {

    updateXAxis(width, height, xAxis)
    updateYAxis(width, height, yAxis)

}

barChartAxisRendered = true

renderBars(data, yScale, xScale, margin, metric, countryID)
};



function renderBars(data, yScale, xScale, margin, metric, countryID) {

let selectDataForBarCharts = d3.select("svg")
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)

selectDataForBarCharts
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .merge(selectDataForBarCharts)
    .attr("fill", d => setBarColor(d))
    .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d[countryID]))
    .attr("width", (d) => xScale(d[metric]))
    .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
    .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)

 selectDataForBarCharts
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .merge(selectDataForBarCharts)
    .attr("class", "casesPerCapitaValues")
    .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
    .attr("x", d => xScale(d[metric])-10)
    .attr("y", d => yScale(d[countryID]) + 13)
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .style("font-size", "10px")
    .text(d => d.casesPerCapita)       
}
```

Comment: make a different selections for texts and rects, or make a `g`roup containing corresponding rect+text of one row

Comment: Thanks that works. I'd be happy to accept it if you wanna post it as an answer

Comment: sure, just did. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code breaks because you overwrite the rectangles with text. Make a different selections for texts and rects, or make a group containing corresponding rect+text of one row.